# SET SCAN OFF with Thin Driver

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, dbunit

I use DbUnit to populate test database with test data before executing tests.

Fragment of my ant script:

```
<taskdef name="dbunit" classname="org.dbunit.ant.DbUnitTask" classpath="dbunit-2.2.jar" />

    <target name="load">
        <dbunit driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost/XE"
            userid="user"
            password="pass">

            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="ojdbc14-10.2.0.1.0.jar"/>
            </classpath>
            <operation type="REFRESH" src="testData.xml"/>
        </dbunit>
```

In my test data I have a couple of values with &xx; values. This data does not get inserted as it is interpreted by oracle as variabl.

I would like to change session property SET SCAN OFF when connecting to database.

I found out that I can pass it in as JVM param using `-Dparam=value`. I tried `-Dscan=off` but it didn't work.

Comment: I doubt that Oracle interprets the & as a variable. This is an SQL*plus thing, which is not involved here. Can you show us the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was a problem with old version of DbUnit.
I upgraded to 2.4.8, used `org.dbunit.ext.oracle.Oracle10DataTypeFactory` and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because `SET SCAN {OFF|ON}` is a SQL*PLUS command. Perhaps elaborate on your problem. Why do you need to call this from your Java app?

Comment: I described situation in more details in the question.